# I use 1 page but it seems 2 application in phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new on Android. I am writing an application. This application use 1 page but I download this application to android phone, it seems 2 `"MoonDroid"` application. `"MoonDroid"` is my application name.

*My application code:*

```
package com.enesmoon.moonandroid;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

String mesaj;
String kullanici;
String sifre; 
Button oyunabasla;
Button kayitol;
Button girisyap;
EditText et;
TextView tv;
TextView yazialani1;
MediaPlayer mpAudio;
ListView lv;

//int sayi = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    oyunabasla = (Button)findViewById(R.id.oyunabasla);
    kayitol = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kayitol);
    girisyap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.girisyap);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etYaz);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yazi_enestarafindankodlanmistir);
    yazialani1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yazialani1);

    kayitol.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    girisyap.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   // bPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sarkibaslat);
   // bPause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sarkidurdur);
   // mpAudio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
   // mpAudio.setLooping(true);

    oyunabasla.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //tv.setText(et.getText());
        //tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        //String kullanici = "abc";
        //String sifre = "123";

        try{
            //HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mucosoft.no-ip.org:2/kullanicilar/moonstalker/moondroid/aktif.php");
            //httpclient.execute(httppost);

            URL sistemaktif = new URL("http://moonstalker.esy.es/proje/moondroid/aktif.php");
            BufferedReader in0 = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(sistemaktif.openStream()));

                    String inputLine0;
                    while ((inputLine0 = in0.readLine()) != null){
                        if(inputLine0.equalsIgnoreCase("aktif")){
                            tv.setText("basarili!");
                            String oyunaktif = "evet";
                            yazialani1.setText("");
                            kayitol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            girisyap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            oyunabasla.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                    }
                    in0.close();
        }catch(Exception e){yazialani1.setText("Hata! Bağlantı sağlanılamadı! İnternet bağlantınızı kontrol edin.");
        yazialani1.setTextColor(Color.RED);}
        }
    });

    /*
    URL oracle = new URL("http://moonstalker.esy.es/proje/moondroid/sistem/index.php?kullanici="+kullanici+"&&sifre="+sifre);
    BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

            String inputLine1;
            while ((inputLine1 = in1.readLine()) != null){
                tv.setText("Basarili:!"+inputLine1);
                yazialani1.setText("");
                if(inputLine1.equalsIgnoreCase("basarili")){
                    tv.setText("x2 basari!");
                    digersayfa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
            }
            in1.close();*/

    /*bPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {mpAudio.start();}
    });
    bPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {mpAudio.pause();}
    });*/

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.enesmoon.moonandroid.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/svScroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yazi_enestarafindankodlanmistir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sayfa2yazi1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Enes tarafından kodlanmıştır."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oyunabasla"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="Oyuna Başla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kayitol"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oyunabasla"
            android:text="Kayıt Ol" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/girisyap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kayitol"
            android:text="Giriş yap" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etYaz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/yazialani1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Bekleniyor..."
android:textSize="30dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check for duplicates in Application Manager on Phone?

Comment: I checked now. it seems 1 application in application manager but 2 "moonandroid" in menu.

Comment: Mb second - is shortcat?) try to delete both and reinstall

Comment: I didn't understand you. I try delete and reinstall a lot of times. This is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/X1EUet1.png

Comment: I think you add   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> tag twice in maifest file!!

Comment: Thanks @bpA , problem solved.

Comment: Now please answer your own question ... :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem: i added this code 2 times.
Answer: Delete this code 1 times.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```